# HTML created but style = null

Tags: javascript, android, html

I run my script on a galaxy tab. I have a strange problem I create a HTML element (div) and once I try to acces to the style attribute, I have an error message telling me that style is null.
Here is my code :

```
 var DIVOU = document.createElement('div');
console.log('Style DIVOU '+DIVOU.style);
```

The log message :
"06-12 13:19:08.530: D/Javascript Log(18668): Log Style DIVOU null"
If you have any idea, thanks in advance.

Comment: obviously, you dont have any "style" in it!

Comment: is this your whole code?

Comment: You need to add some style to it, if you've just created it it wont have any.

Comment: Comeon guys, OP says he's getting an error when accessing `DIVOU.style`. That object should exist before its properties can be set!

Comment: Umh... `console.log('Style DIVOU '+DIVOU.style);` should print `Style DIVOU [object CSS2Properties]` or something like that, depends on the used browser.

Comment: @Teemu: in Chrome, when run in the console this code logs: `Style DIVOU [object CSSStyleDeclaration]` - if it's a document element I believe that it _should_ have a `style` property by default.

Comment: @Quantas94Heavy Exactly, since `style` is supposed to be a property of almost any HTMLElement. OP is getting `null`, how one can set something like `DIVOU.null.backgroundColor = '#ff0';`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any styles assoociated with it!

First add some styles then log it!

Comment: The object isn't supposed to have a default style when created ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that the html file had not meta tag with content-type. The stock browser of Android seems not able to correctly read html files without that.